# Getting file name from FileUpload control - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need the full client path of the file on the server side so that I can use a library to get text from the document. It appears that due to security reasons, IE8 replaces the file name with

```
C:\fakepath\document.doc
```

Is there a way to get the full path to the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the user enables that setting (disabled by default) in IE8 can you send the full path.

Tools >> Internet Options >> Security tab >> Custom Level (for selected zone) >> Misc section, check Enable for "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server".

Answer (score 0):

No.

For security reasons, IE will not send the path to the server.  There is no way to get it.

You might be able to use Flash, though.

Comment: That's not true, there is a way to get it.  See my answer.

Comment: @jacerhea: I meant on the server.